# JavaScript- Lazy Evaluation of Array Issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display results in datatables. However, the two arrays which I try to convert to strings (repo_contributor[key] and repo_langauges[key]) are returning empty that is the dictionary repo_table_data will always have the contributors and languages values empty. Even though most of them are populated with values.

Please find the code below

```
function populateDataTable(repo_contributor,repo_langauges){
    for (var key in repo_contributor){    
        var repo_table_data = {};
        repo_table_data['repo_name'] = key; 
        repo_table_data['contributors'] = repo_contributor[key].join();
        repo_table_data['languages'] = repo_langauges[key].join();
        console.log(repo_table_data);
        $scope.repo_info_list.push(repo_table_data);
    }
}
```

However, when I **do not** use join they do get populated in the dataTable but a bit later(lazily I believe). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You have to somehow synchronize the producing part and the consuming part of the data. For instance, using promises, ie. the producer could provide a promise that gets fulfilled when repo_contributor and repo_langauges gets populated. Here on the consuming part, execute this piece of code only upon promise resolution.

Comment: I'd suggest confirming that lazy population is the issue and not the join, by saying `repo_table_data['contributors'] = [ repo_contributor[key].join() ]`.